# Check values of local variables in subroutines from outside

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

How do you check values in Fortran like in Matlab? For example in the little program under, why does it show `c=0` in main when it is `c=36` in the subroutine `testing`? How do you make it so `c=36` in the main program?

Can you call on the value `c` in some sort of way?  I understand that in the main program the variable `c` is either undefined or has value `0`, but is there a way to save the value of `c` in the subroutine so you can use it again in other subroutines, without calculating it again?

When the program is quite large it is handy to check values as you go.

```
program main

use test

implicit none

integer :: a,b,c

call testing(a,b)

write(*,*)'Test of c in main program',c


end program main



module test

implicit none


contains


subroutine testing(a,b)

integer :: a,b,c

a=2
b=3

c=(a*b)**a

write(*,*)'Value of c in subroutine',c

end subroutine testing

end module test
```

Comment: Are you asking "why is the value of the variable `c` in the main program (which is undefined) not the same as the value of the variable `c` in the subroutine?"?

Comment: No,  more like how you call on the value c from the subroutine 'testing', so that it becomes 36 in the main program.

Comment: See my comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604523/fortran-reusing-a-variable-in-different-subroutine#comment58893727_35604523 and @VladimirF's comment next to it.

Comment: You should spend some effort trying to understand _scope_ in terms of Fortran (and that Matlab is different).  You could call the variables in `testing` as `dog`, `cat` and `mammoth` without making any difference to the effect of the code: does it make sense in that context to ask the question "how can I make the variable `c` in the main program have the value of the variable `mammoth` in the subroutine?" without the effort pointed to by @HighPerformanceMark's comment?

Comment: No,  guess not  francescalus, i understand why it is 0 or undefined, but is there like a way to save the value of c in the subroutine so you can use the value of c in other subroutines, without calculating it again?

Comment: I've tried to clarify the question based on your comments.  If you feel it doesn't help, then please revert that edit.

Comment: Check values how? How do measure if it's okay? What do you do if it isn't?

Answer (score 3):

It is important to learn about [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29) in programming languages.

Every name (identifier) has only a limited range of validity.

If you declare some variable inside a subroutine

```
subroutine s
  integer :: i
end subroutine
```

than the `i` is valid only in that subroutine.

If you declare a variable in a module

```
module m
  integer :: i
contains
  subroutines and functions
end module
```

then the `i` is valid inside all those subroutines and functions and also in all program units that `use` that module.

However, that does not mean that you should declare the variable in the module and just share it. That would be more or less a [global variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable). This is reserved only for certain cases, where that is necessary, but not for getting results out of your subprograms.

If your subroutine just computes something and you want to get the result of that computation you have two possibilities:

**1.** pass it as an additional argument, which will be defined by the subroutine

```
subroutine testing(a, b, c)
    integer, intent(in) :: a, b
    integer, intent(out) :: c

    c = (a*b) ** a
end subroutine
```

you then call it as

```
call testing(2, 3, c)
print *, "result is:" c
```

**2.** Make it a function

```
function testing(a, b) result(c)
    integer, intent(in) :: a, b
    integer :: c

    c = (a*b) ** a
end function
```

and then you can use directly

```
c = testing(2, 3)
print *, "result is:", c
```

or just

```
print *, "result is:", testing(2, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the desired behaviour. Basically the calling routine should know nothing about the subroutine except for how to call it and what to get back. This is called encapsulation.

You can make variables accessible to the calling routine by declaring it in the module itself, and not in the subroutine:

```
module test
    implicit none
    integer :: c

contains

    subroutine testing(a, b)
        implicit none
        integer :: a, b

        a = 2
        b = 3
        c = (a*b) ** a

        write(*, *) "Value of c in the subroutine: ", c
    end subroutine testing

end module test

program main

    use test
    implicit none
    integer :: a, b

    call testing(a, b)

    write(*, *) "Test of c in the main program: ", c

end program main
```

Note that you must not declare `c` in the main program, as it will get the variable from the module.

You could also use a `COMMON` block, but modules are far superior.